# store fid of file_load into profile2

Tags: 7, users, files

I programmed a multi-step form using the drupal form API. On the first page is
a user image file upload using the drupal managed field **managed_file**. When the form is stepped thru to the end and submitted, the already in the single steps validated data will be stored into profile2, by creating a profile2 object with `profile_create` and set the assign the fields.
This all works without problem. But how can I store the FID of the uploaded file to the profile2 user_image field? A s I saw in mysql, the file FID and the measurements of the image are stored in the field table.

I have this (file_load code snippet is untested) in the form submit step, where the data gets stored into profile2:

```
$profile = profile_create(array
    'user' => $new_user,
    'type' => 'main'));
$profile->field_firstname['und'][0]['value'] = $user_data_collection['t_1_1'];
// ... 
if (isset($user_data_collection['t_1_22'])) {
    $file = file_load($user_data_collection['t_1_22']);
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    file_save($file);

    $fid = $file->fid;

    // --- how can I store the FID, x and y measurements of the image?
    // ...
}
// ...   
profile2_save($profile);
```

Can somebody give me a hint? I was searching on google but did not find an answer to my question. Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
This is how I solved it now. Since I work with an **"managed_file" Field** in the form, and later for displaying the image file via the `theme()` fct I do not have to care about resizing. This is done due to the image cache / theme fct's with a properly defined image-style.

```
$profile = profile_create(array(
   'user' => $new_user,
   'type' => 'main'));

//...

if (isset($user_data_collection['t_1_22'])) {
   $file = file_load($user_data_collection['t_1_22']);
   // --- Flag that this file is permanent and should not be deleted.
   $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
   // --- save file object to the database
   file_save($file);

   // --- get original x/y measurements for this image
   $img_info = image_get_info(drupal_realpath($file->uri));
   // --- store fid. x and y to profile 2
   $profile->field_image_user[
      'und'][0]['fid'] = $file->fid;
   $profile->field_image_user[
      'und'][0]['width'] = $img_info['width'];
   $profile->field_image_user[
      'und'][0]['height'] = $img_info['height'];
}

//...

// --- save profile data
profile2_save($profile);
```

So all seems to work and have the solution that I needed.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are asking how to save user picture. Users table holds the place for picture.

```
$account = user_load($new_user->uid);
user_save($account, array('picture' => $fid));
```

EDIT

Profile2 module is based on entities using Entity API module. You can use `entity_metadata_wrapper('profile2', $profile->pid)` to get a metadata object. This object will hold the properties (native profile2 fields) and Fields (additional properties plugged in via field api or Field Admin UI)

```
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($account, 'main');
$profile_w = entity_metadata_wrapper('profile2', $profile->pid);
$proflie_w->field_myfield->value(); // This is a read operation
$proflie_w->field_myfield->set('new value'); // This is write operation
$proflie_w->save(); // Finaly save the things
```

You can bypass metadata wrapper.

```
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($account, 'main'); // Loading existing profile instance
OR
$profile = profile2_create(array('user' => $account, 'type' => 'main')); // Providing a new profile instance
$profile->field_myfield = "new value";
$profile->save();
```

NOTE: you can check all your listed properties using foreach operation on the wrapper object.
e.g.

```
$profile_w = entity_metadata_wrapper('profile2', $profile->pid);
foreach($profile_w as $key => $obj){
   debug($key) // give you name of your property
```

Comment: I keep an extended user profile with about 20 fields like pers. interest, work exp., education and all the likes. In that extended profile is also the user picture and a company logo stored. I've written a profile edit page (is the extra page to the user account data). All works great there. The form I programmed above is combined with the user registration, I need to store the picture in the profile2 data fields along with the other profile data. I am just confused because besides the FID are also the measurements of the picture stored in the mysql field table. There should be a way to do so.

Comment: Yes, I had the feeling, that I will have to respect the entity API somehow. So I think the way to go is to use the first code snippet. Question is, I create a **new profile** with *profile_create()*. So using the entity_metadata_wrapper() fct, is there already a pid availble in the returned object? Because in my App at that point I store a new profile2 object. See my snippet in the question. Maybe I have to call *entity_metadata_wrapper('profile2', $profile)*, with the profile object instead of the object field pid? Then I would have to store the single values of the image field (x, y, fid)?!

Comment: You can skip the loading process. Focus on second snippet block. Do not load it as you are creating a new one. Directly manipulate the field_xyz properties of profile object and then call $profile->save(); this is it :)